# Как запретить копировать в буфер обмена

Tags: delphi, vcl

Мне нужно запретить копировать текст из `RichEdit`
Я решил переопределить WM_COPY У своего компонента

```
TArticleRichEdit = class(TRichEdit)
  private
    procedure WMCopy(var Message: TWMCopy); message WM_COPY;
  end;

procedure TArticleRichEdit.WMCopy(var Message: TWMCopy);
begin
//
end;
```

Но почему то при копировании ctrl+c либо ctrl+ins не срабатывает обработчик

Comment: `WM_COPY` используется для `Plain text`. Возможно, проще запретить выделение текста в (к примеру) `OnSelectionChange` ?

Comment: c `OnSelectionChange ` не очень хороший вариант , поскольку пользователь может выделить и удалить к примеру выделенный текс. это допускается, но не скопировать

Answer (score 1):

есть много вариантов, к примеру

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
 if (Key=#22) or (Key=#3) then Key:=#0;   // 22 = [Ctrl+V] / 3 = [Ctrl+C]
end;
```

---

вариант №2 ([оригинал](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/clipboard_spy_2.htm))

```
...
 var
   Form1: TForm1;
   NextInChain : THandle;
 implementation
 uses ClipBrd; 
...

procedure WMDrawClipboard(var Msg: TMessage) ; message WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD;  
procedure WMChangeCBChain(var Msg: TMessage) ; message WM_CHANGECBCHAIN;
...

procedure TForm1.WMDrawClipboard(var Msg:TMessage) ; 
begin
  if Clipboard.HasFormat(cf_text) then
  begin
   Memo1.Lines.Clear;
   Memo1.PasteFromClipboard
  end
  else
  begin
   // работа других форматов
  end;  
  //pass the message on to the next window  
if NextInChain <> 0 then
   SendMessage(NextInChain, WM_DrawClipboard, 0, 0) 
end;

procedure TForm1.WMChangeCBChain(var Msg: TMessage) ;
 var   Remove, Next: THandle;
 begin
   Remove := Msg.WParam;
   Next := Msg.LParam;
   with Msg do
   if NextInChain = Remove then
    NextInChain := Next
   else
   if NextInChain <> 0 then
    SendMessage(NextInChain, WM_ChangeCBChain, Remove, Next) 
end;
...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject) ; 
begin
  NextInChain := SetClipboardViewer(Handle) ; 
end;
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно как из оригинального куска кода(Вариант 2) запретить копировать  именно из RichEdit